# java.sql.SQLException: Missing defines

Tags: oracle, jdbc

We have a very simple Java code which executes an Oracle stored procedure using CallableStatement API. An Oracle stored procedure doesn't have an OUTPUT parameter defined, however in the Java Code we are trying to register an OUT parameter and retrieve it :

```
 cs = cnDBCon.prepareCall("{call "+strStoredProcedureName+ "}");
 cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.NUMERIC);
 cs.execute();
 int isOk = cs.getInt(1);
```

According to Java API ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#getInt-int- ) when a return value is SQL NULL, the result is 0.

It worked perfectly fine when we were running on Java7/WebLogic 12.1.3. Since we switched to Java8/WebLogic 12.2.1 we started to get the error :

> java.sql.SQLException: Missing defines
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.Accessor.isNull(Accessor.java:744)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.getInt(NumberCommonAccessor.java:73)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.getInt(OracleCallableStatement.java:1815)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper.getInt(OracleCallableStatementWrapper.java:780)
>   at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.CallableStatement_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleCallableStatementWrapper.getInt(Unknown Source)

The obvious choice is to update the stored procedure or java code, but I am wondering about the reason the behavior changed. Is it a more strict JDBC driver?

Comment: You will want to check the versions of your Oracle JDBC driver instead of the weblogic version.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel. Yes, it's probably the case, but I was trying to find certain explanation. I want to understand what exactly happening.